# How to reference System variables when selecting a variable group in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a Build Validation Pipeline, defined by a yaml file, which runs when a pull request is created to a specific branch. I am trying to reference the System.PullRequest.targetBranchName predefined variable when selecting a variable group at the top of the yaml:

```
variables:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['System.PullRequest.targetBranchName'], 'QA') }}:
      - group: "Pipeline_Variables_QA"
```

However, the variable group is not selected - variables are not found later in the pipeline.

If I substitute that if statement for this one:

```
  - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest') }}:
      - group: "Pipeline_Variables_QA"
```

It succeeds. The Build.Reason variable has a value of PullRequest when referenced like this but the System.PullRequest.targetBranchName doesn't seem to have any value.

if I assign the variable to another variable:

```
variables:
  - name: targetBranchName
    value: variables['System.PullRequest.targetBranchName']
```

and then in a script `echo targetBranchName`, I get the value as 'QA'.

Where am I going wrong here? How should I be referencing the System variables?

Thanks in advance.

I have tried several different ways of adding the variable:

```
  - ${{ if eq(variables.System.PullRequest.targetBranchName, 'QA') }}:
      - group: "Pipeline_Variables_QA"
```

```
  - ${{ if eq([variables['System.PullRequest.targetBranchName']], 'QA') }}:
      - group: "Pipeline_Variables_QA"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. The expression syntax `${{}}` is for compile time. The variable `Build.Reason` can be got at compile time, so the pipeline works when you use it.  But the variable `System.PullRequest.targetBranchName` is got at the runtime and is empty at compile time. See more info about expression from doc [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=Another%20common%20use%20of%20expressions%20is%20in%20defining%20variables.%20Expressions%20can%20be%20evaluated%20at%20compile%20time%20or%20at%20run%20time.).

In a pipeline, template expression variables `${{ variables.var }}` get processed at compile time, before runtime starts. Macro syntax variables `$(var)` get processed during runtime before a task runs. Runtime expressions `$[variables.var]` also get processed during runtime. So you can echo the value of `System.PullRequest.targetBranchName` in the task. See more info from [Understand variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for explaining - I'm still trying to get my head around what happens at compile time vs runtime.